# Custom event on Kendo UI Upload Widget in Async Mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, file-upload, kendo-ui

I am using a Kendo UI Upload in my project and files are uploaded in async manner. There is an upload event configured in javascript which gets triggered for each file on upload button click because of "autoUpload: false".
Is there a way that I can fire another event before the actual upload event where I can check if user can upload files or not?(or any custom logic)
For e.g. the new event should be triggered only once, and if the logic returns true, then call the actual upload calls(for each file) else return false and show error.

Comment: Take a look at this - https://jpllosa.blogspot.com/2021/02/kendo-upload-with-spring-boot-example.html - it has `autoUpload: false` set. As the answer already suggested, you can put your custom logic in the upload event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your custom logic in the handler for the upload event. If you decide that the upload should not go ahead, you can cancel it with e.preventDefault().

There is a good and simple example of this here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload/events/upload
Example code from that link is as below:

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="photos" />
<script>
    $("#photos").kendoUpload({
        async: {
            saveUrl: "http://my-app.localhost/save",
            removeUrl: "http://my-app.localhost/remove"
        },
        upload: onUpload
    });

    function onUpload(e) {
        // An array with information about the uploaded files
        var files = e.files;

        // Checks the extension of each file and aborts the upload if it is not .jpg
        $.each(files, function () {
            if (this.extension.toLowerCase() != ".jpg") {
                alert("Only .jpg files can be uploaded")
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: But this method is being called for each file. I want to call a single method on click of upload button. Or is it called once only?

Comment: I believe it is called once only. Add some console.log statements or the debugger to confirm.

Comment: It is currently being called for each file. So what I exactly need to do is to limit to the number of files upload in a given time period suppose 1 min. Currently, we are using web api calls to upload, so for each file, an aync api call is made for upload. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The Select event runs just once for a batch, before upload.  So you can set AutoUpload to false, and place your pre-upload logic in the Select handler, then call .upload() when your code is done.

Example:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
.Name("treefiles")
.Async(a => a
    .SaveUrl("./Index?handler=Save")
    .RemoveUrl("./Index?handler=Remove")
    .AutoUpload(false)
)
.Directory(true)
.DirectoryDrop(true)
.Events(events => events
    .Select("uploadSelect")
    .Upload("uploadStart")
    .Success("uploadSuccess")
    .Complete("uploadComplete")
```

))

```
function uploadSelect(e) {

   //do some stuff

   //trigger the upload
   let uploadControl = $("#treefiles").data("kendoUpload");
   uploadControl.upload(); 

}
```

Please note that "UploadStart" does run for each file.